# Google translate detect selection, so images can be swapped

Tags: html, image, google-translate

I have Google translate running on my site and it works great. It has a small drop down at the top and it can translate the whole webpage correctly. One thing remains is the images, definitely google translate can't do this.

What I'd like to do is to detect the google translate selection and then swap-out or redirect the images to the correct ones like between:

```
<img src="logo.png">
<img src="logo_fr.png">
<img src="logo.se.png">
<img src="logo.it.png">
etc....
```

If it possible to figure out the google translation drop down box selection? Also, what's the best way to "toggle" the img src's into the correct language at load time? Maybe a div with the img data populated afterward?